# Fill Bezier Curves

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm having a big problem with the bezier curves in Blender. I'm trying to fill up the curves, but I can't. I have already seen some videos from YouTube, that say that I have to click on the 2D button.

[image]

But when i click on the 2D button, this is what it happens.

[image]

I thought it was a problem with the camera, but:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: could you upload the blendfile?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After you switch from 3D to 2D, you should choose **Both**, **Front** or **Back** instead of **None** in the curve properties drop down menu.

[image]

Also apply the rotation of your curve (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply rotation*), before switching to 2D.

Comment: I've done what you suggested josh sanfelici and it is "almost" the same as the 3rd screenshot, but a bit thicker. But it doesn't fill up and it doesn't keep the same shape.

Comment: then you should upload the file...

Comment: Thank you very much josh! I just applied the rotation and it work!

Comment: no when i applied rotation it is just the same

Comment: Make sure you're using x end y axis only (not z). If not, rotate your curve (And don't forget to apply the rotation).