# Fill bezier curve with Convert To

Tags: bezier-curves

[Fill Bezier Curves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33485/fill-bezier-curves)

I've already checked this out, but it doesn't help, since I already applied the solution suggested.

[image: Here's what I have.]

Here's what I have; there's no fill despite it being constrained to 2d and the fill option being selected. Not sure if this is relevant, but it was originally modeled on the XZ axis, but I rotated it onto the XY one. I made sure the curve was closed as well (toggle cyclic doesn't solve the problem). Help would be appreciated.

Comment: And yeap I think you will need to model it in the XY orientation for it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The First way** to do this...

( *This will work independent of the axis you created your curve object.*)

1. Select your curve.
2. Hit spacebar and search for "convert to" Shortcut (ALT + C)
3. Select "Mesh from curve"
4. If you have not turned on "Mesh : F2" addon do so in the user preference.
5. Enter edit mode with the converted curve selected.
6. Select all the edges and hit F to fill.

-

**The second** way to go.

(*For this method your curve needs to be created in the top view OR in another 
words the XY axis*)

1. Select your curve.
2. Go to Properity panel > Bezier Tab > Shape > turn on 2D shape Button.
3. Make sure "cyclic" is turn on.
4. Select "front" on the fill option.

Cheers let me know if it helps.