# Curve won't fill

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, bezier-curves

I've created a curve that forms a really complicated logo, and no matter what I do it just won't fill. I changed the Shape to 2D, and tried converting it to a mesh, selecting all the vertices and pressing ALT + F, but it just gives me an error saying "No faces filled". I've done it with all the other parts of the logo, but this part just doesn't want to fill. Can someone help me? Here's an image.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. To get better answers please try to keep the questions as clear as possible. Blurring the information for the settings  on the curve is not very helpful... please feel free to add more information using the edit link at the bottom left of your post. If you can plese upload the file so someone can help you determine what the issue is. To upload please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the resulting link as an edit to your original question

Comment: You can follow these steps here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44003/fill-bezier-curve-with-convert-to/44005#44005 ... if the link doesn't help, do upload your file so that we could take a look at it.

Comment: Did you composite the screenshot ? It looks not usual but it's not easy to see the settings.