# How can I model an irregular object made from laser cutting metal sheet

Tags: modeling

I'm new user of Blender and I have a question about modelling. I would like  to create the model of this object:

[image]

It starts from a metal sheet cut with a laser-cutting machine, then manually deformed into the shape in the photo.

I have no idea about how to model this. Searching I found  "[How can I create a hollow sphere with regularly spaced holes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3212/how-can-i-create-a-hollow-sphere-with-regularly-spaced-holes)"
but that isn't my situation.
Can someone help?

Comment: A couple of really useful answers generated from this question.

Comment: If you found an answer that works for you, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could easily do this with the classic combination *Array* + *Curve* modifiers.

[image]

Since your metal sheet seems to be cut in a repeating pattern start by defining a mesh shaped as one module of said pattern. 
Make use of a *Mirror* modifier, if it is symmetrical.

[image]

Add two Bezier Curve objects to your scene, one defining the larger radius of the desired shape, the other defining the shorter radius and the section of the torus like object.

Make sure the smaller curve is set to *2D* in the *Properties Window* so it doesn't accidentally create gaps. Also make sure both curves are at the same scene position and world coordinate as the pattern mesh.

It also helps if the curve origin is set at one of the end vertex for the section.

[image]

Now to the pattern mesh add one *Array* modifier set to *Fit Curve*, and pick the smaller "section" curve. Then add *Curve* modifier pick the same Bezier object.

Adjust spacing and rotations as necessary if the deformation is unexpected.

[image]

Repeat the above steps of *Array* + *Curve* for the larger curve.

[image]

Now adjust the shape and deformations of the mesh by entering *Edit Mode* in either of the curves and playing around with its shape. Move vertex around or alter their *Radius* property for a scaling or collapsing effect.

[image]

[image]

**Disclaimer:** The gaping deformations that naturally happen by stretching a metal mesh won't be recreated using this technique, but you can manually model them while defining your base pattern object, or apply the modifiers and sculpt them over (a copy of) the final mesh if you don't need a non destructive workflow.

Also see related [How to model braided nylon sleeve](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve)

Comment: When I looked at that question I had no clue where I would even begin. I have been using Blender for 3 years. Yet every time I see your answers I learn something new. Good Job. I would love to see your personal work.

Comment: Thanks mate, glad you like it. My personal work is a lot more boring and less flashy than this I'm afraid, that is why I spend too much time here. There is a link to my portfolio in my profile page.

Comment: Just looked great work, and good luck in Group B this world cup. lol

Comment: Hi Ramos, many thanks for help! I would like to ask for clarification. I cannot understand how to deform correctly my mesh with the curve modifier. Always I have strange deformation and never my "mesh segment" fit the curve. I am sure the problem is in my "short radius" axis rotation. I tried to applay rotation before switching to 2D but my "short radius" curve always always flattens out. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33485/fill-bezier-curves#33486 Can you explain me how to correctly create the vertical "short radius" bezier curve? Thanks!

Comment: Don't rotate nor apply any transforms to the section curve, just leave it be in place as is, as a simple 2D curve object. Optionally move it in *Edit Mode* so that the origin point coincides with the starting vertex. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/problems-with-curve-modifier and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64579/why-does-adding-a-curve-modifier-move-my-object-to-the-center-of-the-curve/64581#64581 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51909/mesh-deforming-when-add-bezier-modifier

Comment: Hi Ramos, i'm very sorry but i can't solve. After a lot of experiments I know my problem is that the "short radius" curve sits on XY plane. When I add the curve, how can I place it on the YZ plane like in your 3rd gif image, without rotate it? here you can find my wrong test file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4252" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4252/) many thanks!

Comment: Just rotate the object in *Object Mode* instead of *Edit Mode*, make sure all origins match. Check the linked answers.

Comment: Also scale your section curve by a factor of -1 in the Y axis to invert the shape

Answer (score 16):

Another way to do this would be to use **Tissue add-on**.

[image: final]

1. You need to have two meshes. **Base mesh** (from **Sphere**) and **Component mesh**.

   *Important thing here is the **Sphere** topology. **Tissue** add-on is placing **Component Mesh** on faces of **Base Mesh** so shape and density of faces on **Base Mesh** will determine how it will look at the end.*

   *Also rotation of **Component Mesh** will be important. Remember to **Apply Rotation** for it.*

[image: meshes]

2. Select **Component Mesh** then **Base Mesh** and go to **Create** tab and select **Tessellate**.

[image: tesselate]

3. Move newly created mesh to different layer, go to **Edit Mode** and <kbd>W</kbd> > **Remove Doubles**.
4. Mesh clean up. Select faces as shown in the screenshot (only one block) and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> > **Face Region**. You will have this:

[image: face]

5. Switch to **Edge Select** mode and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Num -</kbd> to shrink selection.

[image: edge]

6. <kbd>X</kbd> > **Dissolve Edges** and you should have something like this:

[image: dissolve]

7. Go back to **Object Mode** and add **Cast Modifier** (Factor 1) and **Solidify Modifier** (this one should always be at the end).

[image: modifiers]

8. Set Shading to **Smooth** and turn on **AutoSmooth**.

### Mesh deformation:

You have couple of possibilities here.

First could be just manually edit mesh with **Proportional Editing**.

Second one (non-destructive) could be using **Lattice**:

[image: lattice]

### Blend file:

[image]