# Create Curved Chicken Wire/Mesh

Tags: modifiers, wireframe

[image]I’m trying to get this wireframe to have curved wires, like chicken wire. I added wireframe and subdivision modifiers, but they don’t seem to affect the curvature of the wires. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/95978/how-can-i-model-an-irregular-object-made-from-laser-cutting-metal-sheet/

Comment: Thanks but not what I'm trying to do. Just need wires to curve, like chicken wire diamond pattern.