# Filling Curves never work; Apply Rotation useless

Tags: mesh, bezier-curves

As the title implies, I can't ever fill a curve of mine.

[image]

I try to align the rotation with "Scaling + 0", closing the curve with "Alt + C", and applying the rotation via "Ctrl + A" yet nothing ever works. It keeps crushing it ala this user's mesh:
[Fill Bezier Curves](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33485/fill-bezier-curves/33486)

[image]

Yet when they apply rotation themselves, it works for some reason as opposed to mine.
Is it because my curve has too many verts?

I want to fill with this method yet I can't find anything that works. I'd appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Found that the mesh needs to be aligned *ALONG* the X and Y axis, as if it's lying on the ground for the fill to work.

All the sources I saw didn't clarify that, only that it "needs to align with the X and Y axis", so I took it as having a value of zero for the alignment in general.